# Twilio - For voice and C# is there way to call in sequence

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

For the voice path and C#....Is there a way for twilio to make the calls in sequence. For example, I have three phone numbers that are returned from my web services. I want twilio to

- Call phone number 1, let it ring for about 30 seconds and if caller # 1 doesn't pick up, then
- Call phone number 2, let it ring for about 30 seconds and if caller #2 doesn't pick up, then
- Call phone number 3, let it ring for about 30 seconds and if caller #3 doesn't pick up, provide a simple message saying please retry dialing your intended number again.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to easily. The [dial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) verb calls a number and gives you several options such as giving it an action url to post to after the call is completed (or not answered) and you can handle it from there. Or you could simply have the dial verb call the first number and specify a 30 second timeout and NO action url which from the dial docs, twilio will fall through to the next verb which could be another dial verb to the next etc until after the 3rd number in which you could then play (or say) a message.

Comment: Do you have any example code??? Here's how I'm doing it. liDialTargets are a list of phone #                             for (int a = 0; a <= liDialTargets.Count(); a++)
                        {
                            twiResponse.Dial(new
                            {
                                action = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + "/" + configSettings.strCallForwardURL + "?MonitorQueue=2",
                                method = "GET",
                                timeout = 20
                            }, liDialTargets[a]);
                        }

Comment: Try something like ```twiRespone.Dial( DialTargets[0], new { timeout = "30"}); twiResponse.Dial(DialTargets[1], new {timeout="30"}); twiResponse.Dial(DialTargets[2], new {timeout="30"}); Response.Play(youMessageURL);```

Comment: @BrandonMichaelHunter If twilio hits the timeout it, and there is no URL specified it will just try the next twiML verb it comes to which in your case would be the next number to try to call. The last verb would be to play the message. Do you not know before hand how many numbers you are going to have to try to call?